# SQL: How to populate a census column with a count of active clients for each date based on admit date and discharge date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the number of active clients on any given date based on a table ('client_table') with three columns: 'client_id', 'admit_date', and 'discharge_date'.

To do this, I've created a second table ('census_table') with two columns: 'date' and 'census'. I need to populate the 'census' column with a count of the number of active clients for each date in the 'date' column (which I've populated with every date from 1/1/2000 to 12/31/2050.

The logic should be that IF 'admit_date' <= 'date' AND 'discharge_date' >= 'date', then the client should be counted in the census for that date, but I don't know how to code this in SQL.

```
SELECT COUNT(client_id) AS census
FROM client_table
WHERE admit_date <= census_table.date
AND discharge_date >= census_table.date
```

This returns error: 
"Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "census_table.date" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "census_table.date" could not be bound."

Comment: Show what you've tried so far. This isn't a free code writing site.

Comment: My apologies. I will update the post.

Comment: I belive Date is a keyword in SQL.  Try wrapping it like: `census_table.[date]`  You are also trying to reference the `census_table` without joining to it somehow first or subquerying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the SQL query that gives me the values I need (and can then average over a defined period of time in Power BI).

```
SELECT [date], COUNT(DISTINCT 
(CASE WHEN admit_date <= [date] AND discharge_date >= [date] THEN client_id END)) 
AS census

FROM client_table, census_table

GROUP BY [date]
ORDER BY [date]
```

Much thanks for the help guiding me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(client_id) AS census,(select date from census_table) as mydate
FROM client_table
WHERE admit_date <= mydate
AND discharge_date >= mydate
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql server told you roughly what the problem is: census_table.date is a multi-part identifier that can't be bound to anything. This is because the first part of the identifier, census_table, doesn't mean anything where you have used it because isn't listed as a table in the FROM part of your query.

It's not clear how you were planning to manage calculating the answer for each date. Maybe you want to go through the dates one by one and use that SQL to calculate the census for each date? In that case, you would replace census_table.date with a query parameter. That would look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(client_id) AS census
FROM client_table
WHERE admit_date <= @query_date
AND discharge_date >= @query_date
```

The way you specify the value for the query parameter would depend on what environment you are using to execute the SQL.

More likely you want to write some SQL to do the whole calculation in one go. If so, you would need to change your summary calculation to summarize by census_table.date rather than giving a single overall total. Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Taking that approach, you could simply add census_table into the FROM part of the statement. Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp