# SQL Server query for calculating daily census

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a problem with a query that populates the daily census(# of current inpatients) for a hospital unit. [This previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724432/sql-how-to-populate-a-census-column-with-a-count-of-active-clients-for-each-dat) is where I found the query.

```
SELECT 
    [date], COUNT (DISTINCT                                                                           
                       CASE WHEN admit_date <= [date] AND discharge_date >= [date] THEN id END)) AS census
FROM 
    dbo.patients, dbo.census
GROUP BY 
    [date]
ORDER BY 
    [date]
```

There are 2 tables:

- `dbo.patients` with id, admit_date, and discharge_date columns
- `dbo.census` has a date column with every date since 2017, and a census column, which is blank

The query populates the census column, but the census count diminishes toward the end of the dates to smaller numbers then it should. For example, there are 65 null values for discharge_date, so there should be a census count of 65 for today's date, but the query produces a count of 8.

Comment: Slight detour....time to start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for close to 30 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins Also, you should get in the habit of using aliases and adding the alias to each column so you know what table the column belongs to. Also would be a good idea to avoid ambiguous names like "date". What is the date? DateAdded? CensusDate? BirthDate?

Comment: Sample data, table structure and desired output would be really helpful here.

Comment: Yes the joins should be updated. This database is siloed for these two tables alone, so there is little need for more explicit naming, but for general practice your advice is solid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably need to account for `NULL` discharge date

```
SELECT [date], COUNT (DISTINCT                                                                           
CASE WHEN admit_date <= [date] AND COALESCE(discharge_date, GETDATE()) >= [date] THEN id END))
AS census

FROM dbo.patients
CROSS JOIN dbo.census

GROUP BY [date]
ORDER BY [date]
```

That is, assuming `[date]` is some sort of current date/time stamp. Also, as per Sean Lange's comment, if you really want a `CROSS JOIN` then you should specify that in the query.

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect! I will find why your answer worked so I don't repeat my error.

Comment: Glad to help. If a patient has not been discharged, then they should have a `NULL` discharge date. You have to specifically account for `NULL` because it's unknown. So if you compare anything to it, it will return unknown. Therefore, by forcing GETDATE() for `NULL` you can actually get a true value. Hopefully that makes sense.